# How to create sphere without indices?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-3.0

I want to create a sphere with only normals, vertices, texture coords and without using indices. But on the Internet there are options only creation with indices. I just create a lib that helps to create 3d objects, and i don't use indices in this library.
If it's possible tell me how?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.